# HTML select dropdown value alignment

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an Angular project and have a select dropdown in my HTML file. In the drop-down, I have 2 bindings in it.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="security.Id" name="securityId">
     <option *ngFor="let c of Users" [ngValue]="c.UserId">{{c.Name}} -
 {{c.LoginId}}
     </option>
</select>
```

Now i want the value of 'c.Name' should be left aligned in dropdown. And value of 'c.LoginId' should be right aligned.

How can i achive this in my current scenario ???

Comment: `c` has a split personality

Comment: @Mr Lister Yes. And i have updated my question also.

Answer (score 0):

Although `<option></option>` is have closing tag like container element but it is not allow inside any other element and not effect if you add element and try to formatting as you want. Please look after add any tag like `span` or else inside it, source code will show nothing except `<option></option>`.

You must go with select dropdown plugin like [Select2](https://select2.org/dropdown) or something else.